Key not found: {columnName}#{randomNumber}
I have the following query in Spark in databricks-
SELECT bu.tenant_id,bu.service_location_id,bu.account_id,bu.commodity_type,bu.commodity_usage,bu.commodity_units,bu.charges,bu.billed_usage_start,bu.billed_usage_end,
CASE 
WHEN al.industry_code_type IS NOT NULL AND al.industry_code IS NOT NULL AND al.industry_code_type= 'sic' 
THEN (SELECT sics_name FROM dev_silver.trend_calculator_poc.mapping_business_type_codes_results 
where sics_code=CAST(al.industry_code AS BIGINT) limit 1) 
 END 
as business_type,  bu.created AS created_at, bu.updated AS updated_at FROM dev_silver.trend_calculator_poc.billed_usage_temp bu,dev_silver.trend_calculator_poc.account_location_temp al 
where al.tenant_id=bu.tenant_id AND al.service_location_id=bu.service_location_id and al.account_id=bu.account_id;

The query is resulting in an error Key not found: industry_code#15252. The error disappears if I remove the where condition in the sub-query in the THEN clause. The column industry_code is present in the table account_location_temp and spelling is also correct. Somehow, it seems related to access of outer table alias al inside subquery but I am not able figure it out. The data is also present for the join so it is definitely not because of unavailability of any result by subquery. Am I accessing the outer table alias in subquery correctly?
Please suggest how this can be fixed

You are not using the table reference as al in the subquery. The subquery has to be like this:
SELECT sics_name FROM dev_silver.trend_calculator_poc.mapping_business_type_codes_results, dev_silver.trend_calculator_poc.account_location_temp al
            WHERE sics_code = CAST(al.industry_code AS BIGINT) limit 1

This is because the subquery is a complete new query so you have to specified all the tables to use

But I need to specify relation with main table in subquery. If I define account_location_temp again in sub-query, how do I define it's relation with main table?

Use a diferent name to refer the table in the subquery, instead of al you can use al1 or auxal

What will changing the alias do? Issue is not with alias. Issue is that the table defined in the outer query is not accessible in the sub-query used inside CASE WHEN
